# SSH into a remote server in a Jenkins pipeline using withCredentials

Tags: jenkins, ssh

I want to SSH into a server to perform some tasks in my Jenkins pipeline.

Here are the steps that I went through.

1. In my remote server, I used `ssh-keygen` to create `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`
2. I copied the string in the `id_rsa` and pasted to the `Private Key` field in the `Global Credentials` menu in my Jenkins server.

[image]

3. In my Jenkinsfile, I do

   `stage('SSH into the server') {
               steps {
                   withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(
                       credentialsId: '<ID>',
                       keyFileVariable: 'KEY_FILE')]) {
                       sh '''
                       more ${KEY_FILE}
                       cat ${KEY_FILE} > ./key_key.key
                       eval $(ssh-agent -s)
                       chmod 600 ./key_key.key
                       ssh-add ./key_key.key
                       cd ~/.ssh
                       echo "ssh-rsa ... (the string from the server's id_rsa.pub)" >> authorized_keys
                       ssh root@<server_name> docker ps
                       '''
                   }
               }
           }`

It pretty much creates an `ssg-agent` using the private key of the remote server and adds a public key to the authorized key.

This as a result gives me, `Host key verification failed`

I just simply wanted to ssh into the remote server, but I keep facing this issue. Any help?

**LOG**

```
++ ssh-agent -s
+ eval 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-xfcQYEfiyfRs/agent.26353;' export 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK;' 'SSH_AGENT_PID=26354;' export 'SSH_AGENT_PID;' echo Agent pid '26354;'
++ SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-xfcQYEfiyfRs/agent.26353
++ export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
++ SSH_AGENT_PID=26354
++ export SSH_AGENT_PID
++ echo Agent pid 26354
Agent pid 26354
+ chmod 600 ./key_key.key
+ ssh-add ./key_key.key
Identity added: ./key_key.key (./key_key.key)
+ ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ./key_key.key root@<server> docker ps
Warning: Permanently added '<server>, <IP>' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.

                                 WARNING!!!
                    READ THIS BEFORE ATTEMPTING TO LOGON

      This System is for the use of authorized users only.  ....



Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

Answer (score 0):

It is failing because of `StrictHostKeyChecking` enabled. Change your ssh command as below and it should work fine.

```
ssh -o "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" root@<server_name> docker ps
```

`StrictHostKeyChecking=no` will disable the prompt for host key verification.

`UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null` will skip the host key checking by sending the key to `/dev/null`

Comment: It's giving me a different output, but it still gives me some errors: `Permission denied, please try again. Permission denied, please try again. Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).`

Comment: `Permission denied` means whatever credentials you are passing is not working and you are not able to ssh to the remote server.

Comment: You can pass the private key file in the ssh command itself using `-i key_file`. Overall command will become `ssh -o "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -i  ./key_key.key root@<server_name> docker ps` 
Here I have  assumed `./key_key.key` is the file where your private key is stored.

Comment: Still getting the same output. I am copy-pasting the key strings. Could that possibly be the error?

Comment: Can you please update your question with more details about the new error you are getting now.

Comment: I added the log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203137/discussion-between-samit-and-dawn17).

Comment: The permission of the file `./key_key.key` should be `400`. Also, I would suggest you to test the ssh command locally first and then put it in jenkins.

Comment: @Dawn17, could you please update the ticket with the solution?